# Nomenclature of Dihydroxyacetone Phosphate

Tags: nomenclature

Why the dihydroxyacetone phosphate is called that way when it has only one OH ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the phosphoester of dihydroxyacetone. One of the -OH groups was used in the esterification reaction.

See [Here](http://guweb2.gonzaga.edu/faculty/cronk/biochem/D-index.cfm?definition=DHAP)

Comment: Mar 16 2020 ... Link is broken, any chance to update to a working one? Thanks!